# Button defined outside of ListView not working

Tags: android, listview

I have a Button outside of ListView and **Button click** (onClickListener) isn't working. I tried android:focus="false" , android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" but I don't know whether I used it correctly. Totally none worked. I'm a beginner to android, please help me fixing it. Thank You.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:baselineAligned="false">

<Button
    android:text="Button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/b1"/>

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/listView1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything that you have set is correct. But just change the layout_width and layout_height properties. Might be the button is back to the list view. So that is the reason it is not appearing.
Try changing listview content in xml as below:

```
<ListView
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:id="@+id/listView1"/>
```

Comment: Button is appearing, but its not recognising the Click (onClickListener not working) .

Comment: Ok then post ur onclicklistener code.So that I can understand where the error is.